# Mod_XSendFile On a Mac

Tags: macos, apache, x-sendfile

I've installed xsendfile on my mac and it is located in the apache modules. I've attempted to enable it via my htaccess file but I continually get an error. When I try to get a list of modules on my apache server via either terminal or php, it's not listed.  Relevant Code/ Server Info listed below:

Server:
Apache/2.2.21 (Unix)

Compiled and installed Via:
apxs -cia -Wc,"-arch i386 -arch x86_64" -Wl,"-arch i386 -arch x86_64" mod_xsendfile.c

In Httpd.conf:
LoadModule xsendfile_module   libexec/apache2/mod_xsendfile.so is enabled

htaccess:
XSendFile on
XSendFilePath /path/to/file/

Error Message:
Invalid command 'XSendFile', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

I appreciate any guidance.

David

Comment: are you using default install or an additional install, i have in the past had problems with multiple installs.  also more of a server fault question.

Comment: @Grady, thanks for your response. Please forgive my ignorance I believe this is an additional install but I'm not 100% sure. Is there a way to tell?

Comment: You can type : which httpd or httpd2 and which axps or apxs2 see it those match process list

Comment: @GradyPlayer, Thanks again, it looks like I'm still using the default install. By the way, should I move this question to Server Fault?

Comment: you will probably get more attention.

Answer (score 0):

I realise that this question is a year old, but for people looking in future the way to do this (on Mac OS X Lion at least) is:

```
sudo apxs -cia mod_xsendfile.c
```

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere else that you need to enable it by adding these line to the apache config, and that using an `.htaccess` file was not sufficient.

```
XSendFile on
XSendFilePath /absolute/path/to/files
```